# Firebase storage don't return downloadURL

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, storage, snapshot

I am using this code to update an image and get the URL, but I can´t get the URL back.

It seems that return some because it can enter in the return of the promise.

I get this code from here: https://gist.github.com/CristalT/2651023cfa2f36cddd119fd979581893

The code work for another user so I this the problems would be in the dependence or in the database rules.

I am authenticated.

```
    <template>

      <div>
        <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" @change="detectFiles($event.target.files)">
        <div class="progress-bar" :style="{ width: progressUpload + '%'}">{{ progressUpload }}%</div>
      </div>

    </template>

    <script>
    import { storage } from '../firebase'
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          progressUpload: 0,
          file: File,
          uploadTask: '',
          downloadURL: ''
        }
      },
      methods: {
        detectFiles (fileList) {
          Array.from(Array(fileList.length).keys()).map( x => {
            this.upload(fileList[x])
          })
        },
        upload (file) {
          this.uploadTask = storage.ref('imagenes/articulos').put(file);
          this.uploadTask.then(snapshot => {
            this.downloadURL = this.uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
            this.$emit('url', this.downloadURL)
          })
        }
      },
      watch: {
        uploadTask: function() {
          this.uploadTask.on('state_changed', sp => {
            this.progressUpload = Math.floor(sp.bytesTransferred / sp.totalBytes * 100)
          })
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    .progress-bar {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
    </style>
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "vue-change-your-home",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Single page make in vue",
  "author": "enrikiko <enrikiko_91@hotmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "0.0.22",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.9",
    "firebase": "^5.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuefire": "^1.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

this are the storage rules:

```
 service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

this is my firebase.js:
    import Firebase from 'firebase'

```
/**
 * Pega aquí los datos de tu proyecto firebase
 */
const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "++++******-sU0qfey9278aBIDP6zo",
  authDomain: "*+****+.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*****.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "+++++",
  storageBucket: "**.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "**"
  });

export const db = firebaseApp.database()
export const storage = firebaseApp.storage()
export const auth = firebaseApp.auth()
// export const notif = firebase.messaging()
```

in the terminal this is what I get:

```
$route
downloadURL:"" --->here shoud get the URL
file:ƒ File()
progressUpload:100
uploadTask:Object
authWrapper_:Object
blob_:Object
chunkMultiplier_:1
errorHandler_:ƒ (error)
error_:null
location_:Object
mappings_:Array[15]
metadataErrorHandler_:ƒ (error)
metadata_:Object
```

Thank so much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i had the same problem, i tried a lot of stuff, but the simply one solution i found was:

---

**to change the Firebase versión in my package.json i switched to:   `"firebase": "^4.6.2"`.**

---

I am not sure what's happening with the 5.0.2 version. Even when that solve the problem i am still looking for the docs of the change maybe we need to use the snapshot in a different way. will see.
 Good luck! ;)

-- BlisS

Update:

The issue is that the snapshop no longer own the downloadURL at version 5, now you have tu use the method getDownloadURL that belongs to the ref, just like pushups said, something like this:

```
const fileRef = firebase.storage()
    .ref("carpeta")
    .child(file.name);

const uploadTask = fileRef.put(file);

uploadTask
    .then(snap=>{
      return fileRef.getDownloadURL()
    })
```

this also works:
return snap.ref.getDownloadURL()

Comment: I finally solved the problem like this:
 `upload (file) {
        
        this.uploadTask = storage.ref('imagenes').child(this.id).put(file);
        this.uploadTask.then(snapshot => {
        this.downloadURL = snapshot.downloadURL;

        })
      }, `

Comment: err TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDownloadURL' of undefined ` const result = await firebase .storage() .ref("CoverPhoto/" + user.uid) .putFile(url) .then((snap) => { snap.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => { console.log("url", url); }) }).catch(err => { console.log("err", err); });`

Answer (score 3):

You can get this to work with Firebase 5.2.0 with the following code.

The UploadTaskPromise yields a snapshot. The snapshot has a ref property. The ref property has a getDownloadURL() function which returns a Promise. That Promise gives the downloadable url once it's available.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL

```
uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        // do something with url here
    });
});
```

Comment: err TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDownloadURL' of undefined

`  const result = await firebase
      .storage()
      .ref("CoverPhoto/" + user.uid)
      .putFile(url)
      .then((snap) => {
        snap.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          console.log("url", url);

        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);

      });`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';


launchImageLibrary({quality: 0.5}, response => {
      let data = response.assets[0];
      const uploadTask = storage()
        .ref()
        .child(`/uploadedphotos/${Cid}`)
        .putFile(data.uri);

      uploadTask.on(
        'state_changed',
        snapshot => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          if (progress == 100) Alert.alert('File Upload Complete');
        },
        error => {
          Alert.alert(error);
        },
        () => {
          uploadTask.snapshot.ref
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(downloadURL => {
              console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
            })
        },
      );
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.